# Command line apk build - are people using apkbuilder or com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder?

Tags: android, apk

Working on automating a command line build of an Android app.  The apkbuild step doesn't seem to have an associated ant task, and I just read that in the Android 3.0 SDK, apkbuilder is being deprecated.  Are people using com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the existing ant targets provided in $SDK_DIR/tools/ant.